# Find dimensions of specific aspect ratio for rectangular prism of given volume?

Tags: 3d, volume

So, I have a given volume, which must remain constant, and I need to find length, width, and height for a rectangular prism with that volume, scaled to a given ratio (Say, 7:1:1 length:width:height for instance).

Obviously I can take the cube root of the volume as a starting point, for a 1:1:1 ratio rectangular prism (aka a cube of course). But how do I go about taking that value and finding the 7:1:1 dimensions I'm looking for from there?

If you could keep math notation to a minimum in the answer, I'd appreciate it. I'm a dumb programmer with limited formal schooling in math. I like math, but I don't speak it. If you do need to write the answer in math notation, please include an explanation for what it represents in simple arithmetic? Thanks!

Comment: If you stack $7$ cubes of the same size, they become a rectangular prism of $7:1:1$ ratio.

Comment: With a volume 7 times the original, yes...
So could I divide the original volume by 7 and take the cube root of that to get the width and height value?

Comment: Yes. So the rectangular prism of $7:1:1$ ratio has the given volume, which is equal to $7$ times the original volume of each cube.

Comment: So in my programming modality, this should work, where v is volume?
w = (v / 7) ^ (1/3);
h = w;
l = w * 7

Comment: Ah, in other words following your variables, since $l = 7w$ and $h = w$, the given volume would satisfy $V = l \cdot w \cdot h = 7w^3$. Then you can find $w$ from $V$.

Comment: I think that's what I was doing there? Let me break it down and see if you agree: 
$$V = 7w^3$$  
$$V \div 7 = w^3$$
$$\sqrt[3]{V \div 7} = w$$
(Trying the math formatting for the first time lol)

Comment: Yes, I agree. Good!

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I really appreciate the concrete hint you gave me that got me over the visualization hump :-)

Answer (score 1):

Taking the given ratio $7:1:1$ as an example.

Imagine there are $7$ cubes of the same size (to be determined). If one stacks the cubes, they would become a rectangular prism of $7:1:1$ ratio. If the rectangular prism has a volume $V$, then each cube would have a volume $\frac V7$, and the OP knows how to find the dimensions of each cube.

Rewriting the same process in variables. Let $w$ be the width of the rectangular prism, then its length $l=7w$ and its height $h = w$. The given volume $V$ would satisfy $V = l\cdot w\cdot h = 7w^3$, i.e.

$$w = \sqrt[3]{\frac{V}{7}}.$$

(Editing ephemeral and temporary comments into an answer.)